# How to add caption for check box?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How can I add captions for the check box for the below format which is similar to following image.[image]

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/kdur163h/2/

Code:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true"  style="margin-right : 5px;margin-left : 5px" id="progress_list" data-filter-placeholder="Filter Names" >
<li data-icon="false"  class="listitem"><a href="#" onClick='#'>Jashwin <input type="checkbox" name="submt_photo" id="submt_photo" class="custom" checked ><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Identity" id="submt_Identity" class="custom" ><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Address" id="submt_Address" class="custom" checked ></a></li>

    <li data-icon="false"  class="listitem"><a href="#" onClick='#'>ravi kiran <input type="checkbox" name="submt_photo" id="submt_photo1" class="custom" checked ><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Identity" id="submt_Identity1" class="custom" ><input type="checkbox" name="submt_Address" id="submt_Address1" class="custom"  ></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: That's what `<label>` is for.

Comment: The correct HTML code would be http://jsfiddle.net/kdur163h/3/ but there are default styling by jQuery UI that doesn't style it like you'd want. Maybe some option in jQuery UI exists? (I added a fieldset, grouping all form elements and with a legend as a heading + **label** elements - what you call "caption" - with for attribute having same value as the id attribute of input)

Comment: Bad UI and UX. User cant check/uncheck the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 content property to add the text below each checkbox.

Add `title` attribute to the checkbox with its desired value.

EG :

`<input type="checkbox" title="1" name="submt_photo" id="submt_photo" class="custom" checked >`

And CSS

```
.ui-checkbox input:after, .ui-radio input:after{
  content : attr(title);
  padding-top:10px;
  display:block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kdur163h/5/)

Comment: But I am unable to see the title in your demo

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `label`s for that.

Do it like:

```
<label for="submt_photo">Submit Photo</label><input type="checkbox" name="submt_photo" id="submt_photo" class="custom" checked >
```